# how is tp along a segment measured in spatstat

Tags: spatstat

I just wanted some clarification on the measurement of tp. It ranges from 0 to 1 along a segment. My question is where does spatstat start the measurement 0. Is it the starting point of the segment as it was digitised ? Or is it from some other convention of the analysis window or aligning with origin point of the window?

If I want to reverse this measurement, that is, if I want that the zero starts from other end of the segment, how can I do it ?

For example in ArcGIS, if I have digitised a line from north to south, I can use the flip tool to change the digitisation from south to north. Is this possible in spatstat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `spatstat` package an object of class `linnet` represents a linear network. It has a component `vertices` which is a point pattern of all vertices (nodes) of the network. It has components `from` and `to` which are integer indices specifying the start vertex and end vertex of each segment. The spatial coordinate `tp` along each segment is measured from the start vertex to the end vertex. 
The choice of `from` and `to` depends on how the object was constructed. You can reverse all of the segments by:

```
oldfrom <- L$from
oldto   <- L$to
spa     <- L$sparse
newL <- linnet(L$vertices, edges=cbind(oldto, oldfrom), sparse=spa)
```

Not sure why this is necessary ...

Depending on your intention, you could also use the component `lines`  which is a spatial pattern of line segments (class `psp`) representing all these segments, so that `L$lines[i]` is the segment from `L$vertices[L$from[i] ]` to `L$vertices[L$to[i] ]`. If you do `df <- as.data.frame(as.psp(L))` then `df` gives the coordinates of endpoints of each segment, with columns `x0, y0` corresponding to `tp=0` and columns `x1,y1` corresponding to `tp=1`.

Comment: Thank you. I need to inverse a few because they were not constructed in the direction they should have been. If they are proper, tp can help in some linear referencing tasks.